# O que significa public static void main(String[] args)?

Tags: java

Quero entender o que significa cada item de `public static void main(String[] args)` no Java e quando devem ser usadas.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

## `public`

É o modificador de acesso do método. Usando este modificador o método pode ser acessado por qualquer classe dentro (e fora) do projeto.

Outros modificadores são `protected`, `private` ou **sem modificador**<sup>1</sup>. [Aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) pode-se ler mais sobre os modificadores de acesso do Java.

## `static`

Define o método como **estático**, isso quer dizer que a classe não precisa ser instanciada para chamar este método.

No exemplo, tenho a classe `Cliente` com os métodos (estático) `FazerAlgo()` e (não-estático) `FazerAlgoDois()`, o uso seria assim:

```
Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
cliente.FazerAlgoDois(); // Este é o método não-estático

Cliente.FazerAlgo(); // Este é o método estático
```

## `void`

É tipo de retorno do método. Este tipo de retorno significa vazio/nada, o método não dá retorno nenhum. Os métodos podem retornar qualquer tipo do seu projeto, até mesmo os criados por você.

## `main`

É o nome do método. Todo e qualquer método precisa ter um nome. Os nomes são definidos pelo programador e geralmente seguem algum padrão convencional definido previamente pela linguagem ou pela comunidade, embora isso seja opcional. [No caso do Java, a própria Oracle define estas convenções.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) A convenção referente a nomeação de métodos diz:

> Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

Em tradução livre:

> Métodos devem ser verbos, em "mixed case" com a primeira letra minúscula e a primeira letra das palavras internas em letra maiúscula.

No Java (e em outras linguagens também) o `main` é o ponto de entrada da aplicação. É o método que a JRE procura para executar a aplicação. Por isso, em alguns tipos de aplicação (como Swing ou console) é obrigatório tê-lo implementado. É possível ver mais detalhes sobre isso em [Por que é obrigatório implementar "public static void main (String [] args)"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151129/18246)

### `(String[] args)`

Define que o método deve receber como parâmetro um array de `String` (nomeado `args`). Nesse caso específico: este parâmetro serve para caso seu programa precise receber algum valor como argumento, isso é muito comum quando o programa é iniciado por outro programa ou pelo terminal (CMD, Shell, Bash, etc.).

Um exemplo muito comum é o [Git](https://git-scm.com/). Quando você digita `git commit` no seu terminal está chamando o Git com o parâmetro `commit`. Todas as "`strings`" que vierem depois do nome do programa serão recebidas pelo mesmo dentro do *array* (`args`). Geralmente a primeira posição do array é o caminho que a aplicação se encontra.

---

<sup>1</sup> Membros sem modificadores de acesso são considerados *package-private*. Eles só estarão disponíveis dentro do *package* que estiverem declarados.

Answer (score 18):

**public:** é a visibilidade, podendo ser **public**, **private**, **protected** ou **default**.

**static:** é opcional, significa que o método pode ser chamado sem que a classe seja instanciada em um objeto, é muito útil para a classe principal (**main**) já que é a primeira a ser executada.

**void:** é o tipo de dado do retorno do método, **void** é usado quando o método não retorna nada.

**main():** nome do método, se tem os parênteses então é um método.

**String[] args:** **args** é o nome da variável local do método e **String[]** o tipo de dado, este tipo é um vetor de Strings.

Comment: **Correção**: `este tipo é um vetor de caracteres.`. `String` é um vetor (ou array) de caracteres, `String[]` é um array de `String`.

Comment: Obrigado @jbueno

Comment: O `static` é opcional?

Comment: @renan. Para o médotos em geral, sim, mas para a classe principal ele é necessário.