# Java tem alguma classe para trabalhar com argumentos de linha de comando?

Tags: java, linha-de-comando

Preciso criar uma app Java desktop, e com isso passar diversos parâmetros do tipo:

> java meuapp.jar -DB c:\base.db -user admin -senha admin

Tem um jeito fácil de pegar esses parâmetros? Algo assim:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
         TipoMap<String> argum = TipoMap(args);
         usuario = agum.get("user");  
         senha = argum.get("senha");
         ...
    }
```

Comment: No `main` você pode passar diversos argumentos, justamente por isso ele recebe um vetor de strings.

Comment: Aqui há algum material que pode ajudar (enquanto ninguém posta uma resposta apropriada): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-java

Comment: Ex.: `public static void main(String args[])` nesse `args[]` é onde você vai tratar os argumentos esperados(no seu caso, user e senha) dentro do seu código. É isso que você quer fazer?

Comment: isso eu sei, quero um jeito fácil e legível de fazer isso.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Uma das bibliotecas mais conhecidas que faz isso é [Commons.CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/). Com ela é possível tratar argumentos da forma como o AP deseja. Com ela estabelece quais as opções possível, o formato e depois processa o que veio pela linha de comando, determinando o que executar. É bem intuitivo e possui boa abstração para se ater ao resultado final e não ao mecanismo de leitura dos argumentos.

Exemplo da documentação:

```
// create the command line parser
CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();

// create the Options
Options options = new Options();
options.addOption( "a", "all", false, "do not hide entries starting with ." );
options.addOption( "A", "almost-all", false, "do not list implied . and .." );
options.addOption( "b", "escape", false, "print octal escapes for nongraphic "
                                         + "characters" );
options.addOption( OptionBuilder.withLongOpt( "block-size" )
                                .withDescription( "use SIZE-byte blocks" )
                                .hasArg()
                                .withArgName("SIZE")
                                .create() );
options.addOption( "B", "ignore-backups", false, "do not list implied entried "
                                                 + "ending with ~");
options.addOption( "c", false, "with -lt: sort by, and show, ctime (time of last " 
                               + "modification of file status information) with "
                               + "-l:show ctime and sort by name otherwise: sort "
                               + "by ctime" );
options.addOption( "C", false, "list entries by columns" );

String[] args = new String[]{ "--block-size=10" };

try {
    // parse the command line arguments
    CommandLine line = parser.parse( options, args );

    // validate that block-size has been set
    if( line.hasOption( "block-size" ) ) {
        // print the value of block-size
        System.out.println( line.getOptionValue( "block-size" ) );
    }
}
catch( ParseException exp ) {
    System.out.println( "Unexpected exception:" + exp.getMessage() );
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/CliArguments.java).

Answer (score 5):

**Sim, tem.**

Sabe aquela classe `main(String[] args)` que é o ponto de entrada da sua aplicação? É nessa variável `args` que os parâmetros digitados ao chamar a aplicação são armazenados.

Quando você fizer

> java meuapp.jar param1 param2 param3

todos esses parâmetros estarão no array `args`

Acho que é interessante você ler [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/93051/18246) resposta

---

Veja um exemplo de como usá-los:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (String s: args) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: isso eu ja sabia. o que eu quero é não ter que percorrer o array e ter que tentar adivinhar qual a ordem dos parametros

Comment: Seria interessante ter colocado essa informação na pergunta.

Comment: Desculpe, poderia me ajudar a explicar essa minha necessidade?
minha pergunta até já foi respondida, mas pode haver outros com a mesma duvida.

Comment: Mas se quiser você pode editar a pergunta.

Comment: @HagaHood só acharia interessante você comentar que sabe usar os parâmetros do método `main`. De qualquer forma eu irei deixar minha resposta aqui para fins de colaboração com outras pessoas que tenham essa dúvida, mesmo ela não respondendo a sua.

Answer (score 4):

Se você usa o *framework* Spring para fazer a injeção de dependência e gerenciar seus *beans*, você pode desacoplar o seu código de fazer buscas em linhas de comando e simplesmente injetar valores lidos do ambiente.

Exemplo:

```
@Component
public class MeuComponente {

    @Value("${usuario}")
    private String usuario;

}
```

Consulte a [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) e verá que os valores injetados são lidos de diversas fontes, sendo a primeira os argumentos de linha de comando, mas  também incluindo propriedades de sistema do Java (*system properties*), variáveis de ambiente e arquivo de configuração do Spring.

Essa abordagem é flexível e facilita testar os componentes individualmente, além de permitir vários mecanismos de configuração do sistema. Por exemplo, o usuário pode definir o banco de dados como uma variável de ambiente, enquanto a senha é passada via argumento de linha de comando e outras configurações padrão estão definidas no arquivo `application.properties` que vai junto com o sistema.

E, se em algum momento precisar acessar os argumentos de forma mais direta, basta injetar [`ApplicationArguments`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationArguments.html). Exemplo:

```
@Component
public class MeuComponente {

    @Autowired
    public MeuComponente(ApplicationArguments args) {
        List<String> dbs = arg.getOptionValues("DB");
        if (!dbs.isEmpty()) {
            carregaDB(dbs.get(0));
        }
    }

}
```

Claro que se você quiser aceitar argumentos de forma mais elaborada como em programas nativos do sistema operacional, é melhor usar outra biblioteca (como a citada na resposta do **@Maniero**), embora minha recomendação geral seria simplesmente não usar Java.

Comment: Obrigado! mas bem que eu queria não usar java desktop, mas como tenho que fazer integração com um sistema que a biblioteca de integração só é fornecida em java, não tenho muita alternativa

Comment: @HagaHood Entendo. Boa sorte. :)