# Por que o método main recebe parâmetros?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

O que significa esse array de String que é passado como parâmetro? De que maneira esses parâmetros podem ser úteis ao desenvolvedor?

Comment: a sua ultima edição me pareceu no intuito de entender o uso, mas a resposta do jbueno responde já: *Esse parâmetro serve para caso seu programa precise receber algum valor como parâmetro, isso é muito comum quando o programa é iniciado por outro programa ou pelo terminal.* - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/93051/3635

Comment: Verdade, devo apagar essa pergunta então?

Comment: Definitivamente não, perguntas duplicadas servem para facilitar outros usuários a buscarem as perguntas apontadas, no caso a sua serve para encontrar a outra pergunta. Só digo que evite editar a pergunta que já esta como duplicata, a não ser que você considere que não seja duplicata, porque ela vai pra fila de analise para reabrir quando você edita. Mas no caso sua ultima edição na trouxe nada de novo a pergunta e não a tornou diferente da outra pergunta. ;)

Comment: Bruno, vi que você editou a pergunta adicionando o "*De que maneira esses parâmetros podem ser úteis ao desenvolvedor?*" - Então eu editei também a minha resposta para esclarecer isso. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

São parâmetros passados por linha de comando.

Por exemplo, este programa:

```java
public class Parametros {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Ha " + args.length + " parametros:");
        for (String s : args) {
            System.out.print(" [" + s + "]");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Para compilar:

```
javac Parametros.java
```

Eis uma forma de executar:

```
java Parametros Teste os parametros aqui
```

Eis a saída:

```
 Ha 4 parametros: [Teste] [os] [parametros] [aqui]
```

O parâmetro `args` corresponde ao que é passado na linha de comando.

Se você rodá-lo simplesmente assim:

```
java Parametros
```

Eis a saída:

```
 Ha 0 parametros:
```

Quanto a utilidade disso, há muitas formas que isso pode ser usado:

- Eliminar a necessidade de ler-se a entrada de algum lugar ou de ter que pedir ao usuário para digitá-la.
- É bem útil para ser usado em scripts (.bat ou .sh). Desta forma, isso possibilita que o seu programa receba parâmetros no caso em que é invocado por um outro programa.

Um exemplo de uso real disso, é o próprio compilador `javac`. Você informa ao compilador os arquivos que devem ser compilados por meio de parâmetros de linha de comando. Outros programas (tais como o Eclipse, o Netbeans, o Ant, o Maven, e muitos outros), utilizam esse mecanismo de linha de comando para invocar o compilador por debaixo dos panos.

Answer (score 0):

Ele vai representar todos os argumentos do command-line quando o programa for executado.

Toda a interação que ocorrer durante a execução do método main da sua classe irá ser realizada através desse array.