# O que significa o equals(Object o) nesse método?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Nesse código:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Aluno outro = (Aluno)o;
        return this.nome.equals(outro);

    }
```

Pra que ele serve?

Comment: `equals(Object o)` é a assinatura do método. `equals` é um método público que recebe um objeto e retorna um valor booleano. É isso que você quer saber?

Comment: Não conheço muito `java`, `equals` não seria uma palavra reservada? @bfavaretto

Comment: [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) é um método da classe `Object`, toda classe java herda de `Object` implicitamente.

Comment: Nope, `equals` é um método da classe `Object` @rubStackOverflow

Comment: Eu não entendi, estou lendo uma apostila da caelum de algoritmos e estrutura de dados.

Comment: Esse código está certo? Parece que está comparando um atributo do objeto com o outro objeto inteiro. Não seria `this.nome.equals(outro.nome)`?

Comment: Isso, eu esqueci de colocar o .nome em this.nome.equals(outro.nome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`equals(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) é, como o *bfavaretto* já disse, parte da assinatura do método - [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/93051/18246) tem mais detalhes sobre assinatura de método. Isso define o nome do método (`equals`) e os seus parâmetros (um `Object` chamado `o`).

O método `equals` é padrão da classe `Object` (todas as classes no Java herdam de `Object`) que, geralmente, tem como função definir se um objeto é igual a outr, por isso ele pede um objeto como parâmetro.

---

Não pude deixar de notar que o código do método está errado, ele sempre vai retornar `false`, pois está comparando um atributo do objeto atual com o objeto que foi passado por parâmetro, veja:

```
return this.nome.equals(outro);
//this.nome => objeto atual
//outro => objeto passado por parâmetro
```

Se a intenção é comparar os atributos `nome`, o código deveria ser

```
return this.nome.equals(outro.nome);
```