# Como posso persistir dados usando ArrayList?

Tags: java, joptionpane

Preciso que minha estrutura de dados ArrayList seja visível em mais de um metodo da minha classe Produtos.

Estou trabalhando da seguinte maneira:

```
package estoque;

import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class produtos {

   public static void cadastro() {
      ArrayList<String> Produto = new ArrayList<>();
      JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
      JTextField field2 = new JTextField();
      JTextField field3 = new JTextField();
      Object[] message = {
         "Código:", field1,
         "Descrição:", field2,
         "Quantidade:", field3};
      Component parent = null;
      int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(parent, message, "Cadastro de Produtos", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
      if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
         String codigo = field1.getText();
         String descricao = field2.getText();
         String quantidade = field3.getText();

         if (codigo.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor, preencha o campo Código!");
            cadastro();
         } else if (descricao.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor, preencha o campo Descrição!");
            cadastro();
         } else if (quantidade.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor, preencha o campo Quantidade!");
            cadastro();
         } else {
            Produto.add(codigo + ' ' + descricao + ' ' + quantidade);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Produto cadastrado com sucesso!");
            System.out.println(Produto);
            Estoque.menu();
         }
      }
   }

   public static void listar() {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Código - Descrição - Produto\n", "Lista de Produtos", 1);
   }

}
```

Da opção menu eu acesso Cadastro e realizo o cadastro de um produto que será armazenado em  `ArrayList<String> Produto = new ArrayList<>();`

Depois eu volto para outra classe chamada Menu e seleciono a Opção Listar, que acessa o método listar();

Nesse método o ArrayList não é global, portando eu não consigo acesso a ele, como eu posso torna-lo global para realizar a leitura neste método ?

Comment: Coloque-o como atributo da classe: `private ArrayList<String> Produto = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Ai o ArrayList Produto não fica visivel no metodo, como eu chamaria ele ?

Comment: Agora que reparei que é estatico. Basta adicionar dessa forma: `private static ArrayList<String> Produto = new ArrayList<>();` assim vira um parâmetro estático de classe, e não de instância.

Comment: Era isso mesmo! coloca como resposta e adiciona uma explicação, para que eu possa marca-la como correta, tinha me esquecido de static, meio que tenho uma confusão em java quando se trata disso!

Comment: Acredito que esta pergunta não será util para ninguém visto que o meu problema foi apenas uma falha na semântica em esquecer o uso de static

Comment: Veja [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93048/18246).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode definir o `ArrayList<String>` como um atributo da classe, fazendo com que o escopo da classe inteiro tenha acesso ao valor, assim você poderá usar e alterar em qualquer método da mesma:

```
public class Produtos {
  private List<String> produtos;

  public void cadastro() {
    produtos = new ArrayList<String>();
    produtos.add("seu produto");
  }

  public void listar() {
    //Os produtos estarão disponíveis aqui também, caso a lista esteja inicializada
    if (produtos != null) {
      for (String prod : produtos) {
        System.out.println(prod);
      }
    }
  }

}
```