# Por que é obrigatório implementar "public static void main (String [] args)"?

Tags: java, método

Por que é obrigatório implementar esse método em uma aplicação Java?

Comment: Esse inicio do Java Significa.
O Método que deve ser iniciado primeiro é publico, estático, não retorna nada é o usuário pode passar argumentos como string "Conjunto de caracteres"

Comment: Não responde sua pergunta por completo, mas pode te ajudar a entender mais sobre este ponto de entrada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/93051/41056

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que significa public static void main(String\[\] args)?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93048/o-que-significa-public-static-void-mainstring-args)

Comment: Basta uma leitura nas duas e dá para ver que o assunto é o mesmo, mas a pergunta não é a mesma, portando não é duplicata. Não podemos fechar perguntas só porque o assunto é o mesmo, isso impediria a maioria das perguntas já feitas. Na verdade olhando as respostas que tem lá não respondem o que foi perguntado aqui, então não faz sentido fechar essa.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

É obrigatório porque toda aplicação precisa de um ponto de entrada. Normalmente o sistema operacional precisa saber onde começa o código, no Java na verdade é o ambiente operacional dele, é o JRE que vai iniciar a aplicação e precisa saber o que chamar primeiro. convencionou-se que seria esse método chamado `main()`, já que outras linguagens usavam algo assim.

Na verdade também precisa especificar qual classe será a principal já que o método `main()` pode existir em outras classes.

O corpo pode ser tão simples quanto apenas chamar um outro método. Não vejo utilidade nisso, a não ser para algum fim muito específico, as outras pessoas faem sem saber porque.

## Nem sempre é obrigatório

Existem algumas situações onde ele não é obrigatório. É o caso de aplicações web que já iniciam por algum outro lugar do [*framework*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101) usado e depois vão chamando o que você programou. Na prática há um `main()`, mas não no seu código.

Também é possível funcionar com apenas um método estático dentro de uma classe considerada principal. Também não vejo vantagem geral nisso, mas é possível segundo uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2897323/221800).

```
class JavaAppWithoutMain {
    static {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/Static.java).

## Assinatura

Na [assinatura do método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) foi convencionado o uso de `String[] args` para receber argumentos de linha de comando - como podem ser vários e pode conter qualquer tipo de informação o ideal seria um *array* de *string*. Também se optou por retornar nada para o sistema operacional, ao contrário de outras linguagens que o fazem. Você pode ignorar essa variável.

Ao contrário de outras linguagens Java preferiu não dar opções e essa é a única assinatura possível. A filosofia da linguagem é simplificar, ainda que seja discutível se isso é uma simplificação de fato.

Há mais detalhes sobre cada componente em [O que significa public static void main(String[] args)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93048/101).

Comment: Olha a resposta está excelente, só que fiquei confuso se o AP quer saber do `main` apenas ou também quer saber dos argumentos (apesar dele não ter citado isto). Todavia já deixo o +1

Comment: Ótima resposta, mas qual a finalidade de passar o "String[] args" como parâmetro ?

Comment: @JoseVieiraNeto a finalidade é que "args" é um array de string que contém os parametros passados no momento da execucao. Veja exemplo: http://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-o-parametro-string-args-em-java/29245

Answer (score 7):

Geralmente, em qualquer linguagens de programação, esse parâmetro representa os dados de entradas que serão passados para seu programa.

Eu não possuo muito entendimento sobre Java, embora já tenha testado isso, e sei como funciona.

Se você por exemplo tem uma classe chamada `Hello` que tem esse `String args[]` como parâmetros, ao você executar o comando `java Hello world`

O resultado dessa `String args[]` será `["Hello", "world"]`.

Eu não sei se em todas as linguagens são assim, mas em todas que eu trabalhei até hoje (Python, PHP e afins), o primeiro argumento que se trata do nome do programa (no meu exemplo é "Hello") sempre está presente.

Isso é muito útil para você passar argumentos para sua aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente esse método significa que na você está tornando a classe que você está implementando como principal.

É ele que faz a execução de todo o código que você construir ou chama-ló.

Comment: O que seria uma classe principal? Acredito que está a se referir ao método de entrada apenas. A classe não desempenha papel pro compilador, e sim o método de entrada.

Comment: @CypherPotato, neste caso não é nem pro compilador, mas sim pra hora da execução que você precisa informar qual será a classe a ser executada. O compilador vive bem sem esse método em nenhuma classe