# Qual a diferença entre String[] args e String args[]?

Tags: java, array, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

Qual é a diferença entre as declarações **`String[] args`** e **`String args[]`** em Java?

Comment: Só a posição dos colchetes, que se tratando de vetor, podem ser posicionados dessas duas formas que o compilador irá entender da mesma forma, mas é recomendável deixar ele perto do tipo e não do nome do vetor. E isso não é exclusividade do método main, é permitido em toda declaração de vetor. o método não muda em nada, continua sendo o método main que recebe um vetor de string em ambas as formas.

Comment: @diegofm não, nem um pouco duplicata, são assuntos **completamente** diferentes, a única coisa em comum é que o exemplo usado está no parâmetro do `Main()` que é circunstancial para a pergunta.

Comment: Isaque, eu editei sua pergunta porque parece que você quer entender a diferença entre as duas declarações e não sobre métodos. Se essa não foi sua intenção, você pode usar o campo de comentários pra me avisar que eu reverto a pergunta para o estado inicial.

Comment: @jbueno, você está correto em sua edição. Gostaria de saber realmente a diferença entre as declarações.

Comment: @renan Também não consigo acreditar nisso. Será que não leram a outra pergunta?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nenhuma. É só uma permissividade da linguagem escrever das duas formas. Uma (`String args[]`) é para facilitar para quem vem do C ou C++ e está acostumado assim, a outra (`String[] args`) é mais intuitiva, já que as duas partes da declaração do tipo da variável estão juntas. O primeiro é esquisito porque uma parte do tipo está em um lugar e a outra parte está junto da variável.

Eu considero que a forma "nova" do Java, que é preferida, seja um erro também, mas é o que tem. O correto seria `[]String`. Assim fica um "*array* de `String`", assim como você tem um `ArrayList<String>`, portanto tem um "`ArrayList` de `String`". `String[]` você tem que ler ao contrário ou ler de forma estranha: "String em um *array*".

Na pergunta original falava-se sobre o uso no `main()`. Por acaso, está sendo usado no `main()`, mas isso tem a ver com declaração de variáveis (parâmetro não deixam de ser variáveis. Se quiser saber algo sobre o `main()`, tem uma [pergunta sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151129/101). As duas formas podem ser usadas igualmente em todas as situações, não existem casos onde só um pode ser usado, nem mesmo na declaração simultânea de várias variáveis no mesmo *statement*, que nem costuma ser muito adequado nesse caso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu ainda não possuo conhecimento em coleções mas pela explicação que você expôs eu consegui compreender a diferença ou no caso a flexibilidade da linguagem. Muito obrigado pelo explicação @bigown.

Comment: `O correto seria []String. Assim fica um "array de String"` isso se pensar em português, se pensar em inglês o certo é "String array", e consequentemente faz mais sentido o `String[]`

Comment: @Math não, mesmo em inglês o correto é *array of strings*. Tem até linguagem que usa o termo `Of` p/ indicar isso, tipo `Array<Of String>` ou `Array Of String`. Assim como o correto é `*char` e não `char*` como se usa. Porque é "ponteiro para caractere(s)". E de fato tem linguagem usa ponteiro como `^char`. Linguagem é minha praia, já pensei muito sobre isso :)

Comment: Curiosidade complementar, a partir do Java 5 temos também [*Varargs*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), (`String... args`), inclusive, `public static void main(String... args)` é sintáxe válida e funcional.

Answer (score 9):

A execução funciona das duas formas sem nenhuma diferença real. A recomendação é que seja utilizada a sintaxe `String[] args` que é mais consistente com a declaração de tipagem do Java.

A primeira também permite a criação de vários `arrays` simultaneamente, facilitando o uso:

```
String[] array1, array2;
```

Comment: Mas a pergunta é qual a diferença. Não é um pedido de recomendação.

Comment: @jbueno mudei a ordem para ficar claro