# Por que o ponto de entrada das aplicações é um método estático?

Tags: independente-de-linguagem, métodos-estáticos

Um método declarado estático significa que ele pertença ao tipo e não a instância de um objeto.

Em uma aplicação console C#, o ponto de entrada é estático:

```
static void Main(string[] args) { ...  }
```

Isso não é só do C#, no Java é o mesmo conceito:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
```

Também não se limita a aplicativos console. Um projeto WPF tem um ponto de entrada estático.

Nas perguntas que já existem sobre o assunto não se explana sobre o `static` além da sua obrigatoriedade sem justificativa e definição:

- [O que significa public static void main(String[] args)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93048/o-que-significa-public-static-void-mainstring-args)
- [Por que é obrigatório implementar “public static void main (String [] args)”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151129/por-que-%C3%A9-obrigat%C3%B3rio-implementar-public-static-void-main-string-args)

Por que os pontos de entrada dos aplicativos são estáticos?

A aplicação em si, inicialmente, não é uma instância de objeto do tipo `Application` ou `ConsoleApplication` (ou seja lá o nome que eu dei para a classe que contém o método de entrada), por exemplo?

Comment: Se o `main` não fosse estático, como você lidaria com os construtores da classe? E se o construtor tiver parâmetros? E se a classe tiver múltiplos construtores? Acredito que o ponto dos *designers* dessas linguagens foi definir um "contrato" simples para o ponto de entrada da aplicação.

Comment: Acredito que seja por conveniência e, possivelmente, por semântica. O `main` é apenas o ponto de entrada do programa e pertence à uma classe que (geralmente) não tem representatividade real: ela só existe para ter o método (poderia ser apenas uma função). E se a classe ter representatividade, a instância pode ser feita dentro deste método sem problemas.

Comment: O `main` não pode ter mais parâmetros como `static main(String[] args, int x)`? @AnthonyAccioly

Comment: Em java, que eu saiba, o fato de receber um array já significa que você pode passar quantos parametros quiser, agora o tipo, é somente string mesmo, se precisar de outro tipo, tem que fazer cast no main após recuperar os parametros.

Comment: Relacionada: [O que significa public static void main(String\[\] args)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93048/5878)

Comment: Não em Java (e que eu saiba também não em C#). Mas o ponto do meu comentário inicial vai além do tipo e quantidade de parâmetros. Quando introduzimos OO na equação temos que resolver todos os problemas de construtores, destrutores, *overloading*, *overriding*, etc, etc, etc. Java não possui um tipo *singleton* (`object`) bem comportado ou funções *standalone*. Um método `static` me parece ser a maneira mais conveniente de garantir esse contrato (basicamente procedural) em uma linguagem OO que não possui mecanismos mais modernos.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inicialmente a aplicação não é instância de nada. E de certa forma isso explica porque o método é estático.

Poderia ser um método de instância, não há nada tecnicamente que impeça fazer dessa forma, só foi assim que escolheram, talvez porque sempre foi assim em outras linguagens existentes antes do C#, a maioria que sequer possuem o conceito de classes e instanciação de objetos.

Poderia mais, poderia deixar definir outro método, talvez até com outra assinatura, deixando até passar outros argumentos. Lembre-se que precisa dizer qual é o tipo que deve usar como *entry point*. E pode ter `Main()` em qualquer tipo sem que seja um ponto de entrada.

O Android instancia objetos e faz o que precisa. Para o modelo do sistema operacional é mais interessante. Mas os sistemas operacionais tradicionais sempre tiveram uma única forma de iniciar uma aplicação. Então eu diria que escolheram assim até por razões históricas, todo mundo estava acostumado fazer assim.

Em linguagens não orientadas a objeto uma função é usada como ponto de entrada e o método estático é o mesmo que uma função.

Acho que entender o [uso do método estático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/101) ajuda entender essa decisão. Ao contrário do que pregam os ideólogos de OOP, um método estático é sempre mais simples de lidar e ele deveria ser preferido sempre onde couber (não cabe em um monte de situação). O `Main()` é um caso que cabe como uma luva.

Não vejo tanta dificuldade assim quanto disseram nos comentários, mas faz algum sentido. A simplificação me parece o melhor argumento para evitar esta funcionalidade que traria pouca ou nenhuma vantagem. Desenvolvedores de linguagens são pragmáticos e analisam os custos de implementar algo, de complicar a linguagem e os benefícios que isso trará.

Um ponto que acho que pode levar em consideração é que você pode querer chamar este `Main()` dentro da sua aplicação. Aí precisa instanciar outro objeto, porque o objeto que iniciou a aplicação é de propriedade do [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101) (a não ser que fique passando ele pra lá e pra cá na aplicação). Se é outra instância, embora fisicamente chamará o mesmo método, está acessando outro objeto, com dados possivelmente diferentes, pode não ser o que deseja.

Em C# pode usar 4 assinaturas diferentes (não simultaneamente):

```
static void Main();
static void Main(string[] args);
static int Main();
static int Main(string[] args);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Main.cs).

Em C# 7.1 pode até mais porque o `Main()` pode ser assíncrono.

Em C# 9 não precisa ter esse método explicitado para *scripts* simples. Não é que ele deixou de ser necessário, o compilador coloca para você. Só faça isso para código *throw away*.