# Passar parametros para arquivo jar

Tags: java

Tenho um exemplo de projeto pronto (bem simples), porem eu gostaria de fazer um configurador de conexão com o banco de dados. Depois de compilado, o sistema cria um arquivo.jar e eu gostaria de saber como passar um parâmetro no executável para chamar o configurador de banco de dados (Ex: arquivo.jar /db).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o objetivo é passar parâmetros para o jar, basta tratar o array de Strings que o método `main` da classe principal recebe, pois é por ele que se passa comandos externos a execução do jar na maquina virtual.

Para exemplificar, elaborei o seguinte exemplo:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MainTeste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String commands = "";

        for(String str : args) {
            commands += str;
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Foram passados os seguintes comandos: " + commands);

    }

}
```

Veja que eu estou varrendo o array recebido pelo main e concatenando numa variavel a parte, para depois exibir. Depois de gerar um .`jar`, basta passar os parametros por uma linha de comando semelhante a abaixo:

```
java -jar seuJarFile.jar comando1 comando2 comando3
```

Veja o código acima, após gerar o jar, funcionando:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Vale destacar que os parametros devem ser separados por espaço, se tiver algum parametro que contenha espaço(como nomes de arquivo ou caminhos, por exemplo), deve ser passado entre aspas duplas.

---

**Tópicos Relacionados:**

- [O que significa public static void main(String[] args)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93048/28595)
- [Por que é obrigatório implementar "public static void main (String [] args)"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151129/28595)

Comment: Ajudou muito, consegui fazer funcionar.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo sua dica, consegui com o código abaixo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String commands = "";

    for(String str : args) {
        commands += str;
    }

    if (commands.equals("db")) {
        TelaConfigDB.main(null);
    } else {
        TelaSplash.main(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Se a minha resposta lhe ajudou, você pode aceitá-la ao inves de replicar. Veja como funciona o site no link que segue: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour