# Como funciona o operador new em Java?

Tags: java, operadores, instanciar-objeto

Não estou entendendo como o `new` funciona abaixo:

```
public Main(){
   System.out.println("");
}


public static void main(String[] args){
   new Main();
}
```

Comment: O que deveria ser `public Main()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom, esse código poderia ser postado de forma completa para dar uma ideia melhor do que está fazendo, mas dá para entender mesmo com essa parte.

Esse é um código que não faz muito sentido em condições normais, mas dá para explicar o que acontece.

O código deve ser mais ou menos isto:

```
public class Main {
    public Main() { System.out.println(""); }

    public static void main(String[] args) { new Main(); }
}
```

Então temos uma classe chamada `Main` que tem um construtor de mesmo nome. Como eu sei que tem um construtor? Bem, o construtor não tem tipo de retorno, a sintaxe indica isto. E sei o nome da classe sem ele estar na pergunta? O construtor tem o mesmo nome da classe sempre, então ele é um construtor da classe `Main`.

Se quer entender melhor sobre construtores pode ler [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Verá que esse construtor faz pouco sentido em um código real. Na verdade quase "tudo" que quiser saber sobre programação pode pesquisar aqui e tem boas respostas, pelo menos as mais votadas. Faça isso.

Quando você cria uma classe pode criar objetos dela. Veja mais em [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101). Em Java para criar um objeto partindo de uma classe você chama o construtor que você criou ou um padrão que o compilador cria para você em certas circunstâncias.

E para chamar o construtor tem que dizer que criará um novo objeto obrigando o uso da palavra reservada `new` antes das chamada do construtor, até para não confundir com uma chamada de um simples método normal.

Então está criando um objeto do tipo `Main` e chamando seu construtor escrevendo nada na tela, que é o que tem dentro do construtor.

Como não está armazenando em uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) o objeto é perdido logo depois da execução da construção. O que é ok nesse código, ele não faz algo útil mesmo, mas em alguns casos talvez queira por em uma variável.

Um código assim sem estado, em geral não precisa de uma classe, de uma instância, o método poderia ser estático e só chamá-lo, algo assim:

```
public class Main {
    public static void Main() { System.out.println(""); }

    public static void main(String[] args) { Main(); }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/New.java).

Ou poderia fazer algo mais simples e com algum sentido.

O outro método é algo padrão da linguagem usado como ponto de entrada da aplicação. Veja mais em [Por que é obrigatório implementar "public static void main (String [] args)"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151129/101).