# O método "main()" pode ser sobrecarregado ou sobrescrito?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, método, sobrecarga, sobrescrita

Li a resposta [O que significa public static void main(String[] args)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/93051/110782), porém ainda estou com duas dúvidas sobre o método `main()`:

1. O método `main()` pode ser sobrecarregado?
2. O método `main()` pode ser sobrescrito?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, ele pode ser sobrecarregado, mas somente o método original é chamado pela JVM. Quanto a sobrescrita, ele não pode, pois é estático.

Referências:
[Sobrescrita](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083876/override-main-method) e
[Sobrecarga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759315/can-we-overload-the-main-method-in-java)

Comment: Obrigado renanzin, esqueci completamente do método estático na sobrescrita.

Answer (score 6):

Em Java esse `main()` referenciado naquela questão **não pode ser sobrecarregado**.

Claro que você pode sobrecarregar um método chamado `main()` mas ele não tem a característica especial de que trata aquela questão. Qualquer sobrecarga neste nome nada tem a ver com o conceito de ser um ponto de entrada da aplicação e Java só tem uma sobrecarga aceita, que é aquela mostrada. Então a resposta depende do que quer dizer na sua pergunta. Minha interpretação é que quer saber sobre este método em específico.

Em C# existem algumas sobrecargas aceitas como ponto de entrada (tem [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) com parâmetros diferentes, retornos diferentes e até assincronicidade), ainda assim só algumas, todas as infinitas possibilidades de assinaturas diferentes são métodos comuns que por acaso tem o nome `Main()`, mas nada tem a ver com este método com características especiais.

E **não pode ser sobrescrito**, pela simples razão que ele é estático e métodos estáticos fazem parte da classe e não da instância, e só os membros de instância fazem sentido serem herdados. A herança se concretiza quando cria uma instância, então um objeto tem todos os seus membros mais os membros do tipo pai. O método estático existe por si só, sem depender de instância.

Pode-se questionar se o método poderia não ser estático. Até poderia, mas seria uma dificuldade grande pra lidar com isso sem nenhuma vantagem importante.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

1. Não. O método main é o ponto de partida da sua aplicação. Se você o sobrecarregar, significa que a assinatura dele mudará e ele será tratado como um método qualquer e seu programa não poderá ser executado.

Sua classe com o método main "diferenciado" ainda poderia ser invocada e utilizada através de outras classes normalmente.

Mas pra executar seu programa, em algum lugar deve existir uma classe com um método main com a assinatura idêntica a que você já conhece.

```
public static void main(String[]);
```

2. Não. Métodos estáticos não podem ser sobrescritos. Sobrescrita (Overriding) é uma característica dos métodos de instância.

Métodos estáticos podem ser escondidos (Hiding). Mas eu não sei o que as boas praticas dizem sobre isso.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8

Ter uma super classe e uma subclasse, cada uma com seu próprio método main significa que seu programa teria 2 pontos de entrada. Seja lá qual for o problema que esteja tentando resolver, com certeza existe um padrão de projeto que seria mais adequado.