# Porque é necessário colocar public static void main(String[] args)?

Tags: java, public

Quero entender a real intensão dessa linha de comando, o que ela faz ? Meu professor não comentou sobre ela apenas iniciou o projeto com ela, nesse caso criei o código:

```
package exemplo;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exemplo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
    float salario_base,salario_liquido;
    System.out.println("Informe seu salário bruto:");
    salario_base=teclado.nextFloat();
    salario_liquido=(float)(salario_base*1.20*0.93);
    System.out.println("O salário líquido é:" + salario_liquido);

    }

}
```

Mas pra que está servindo a publublic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ela é a **função main** do programa, ou seja, a **função principal**. Ela será chamada sempre que você executar o seu código, portando, o compilador só irá executar o código que estiver **dentro dessa função.**

Se você ainda não teve muito contato com programação, e ainda não saiba o que é uma  **função**, não se prenda a esses detalhes, seu professor não comentou porque talvez não seja uma informação muito útil no momento.

Se você quiser saber o **significado mais detalhado** desta função veja o link abaixo:

- [O que significa public static void main(String[] args)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93048/o-que-significa-public-static-void-mainstring-args)