# Imprimir em ordem decrescente em Java

Tags: java

Estou tentando criar uma interface em que notas (decimais) são digitadas, e imprimidas em ordem decrescente, mas estou obtendo alguns erros que não compreendi bem.

Essa é a classe para o usuário digitar a quantidade de alunos x, e assim digitando x notas.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Numeros{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int numAlunos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Forneca a qtde de alunos"));
        float notas[] = new float[numAlunos]; 

        for (int i = 0; i < numAlunos; i++){
            notas[i] = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Forneca nota do aluno"));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numAlunos; i++){
            System.out.println("Nota: "+ notas[i]);     

        }
    }
}
```

Essa é a classe que organizaria as notas decrescentemente:

```
public class App{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Numeros nm = new Numeros();
        for (int i = 1; i < notas.length; i++); {
            for( j = 0; j < i; j++); {
                if (notas[i] > notas[j]); {
                    int temp = notas[i];
                    notas[i] = notas[j];
                    notas[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A primeira funciona corretamente, a segunda diz que não consegue encontrar as variáveis `notas`, `i` e `j`.

Answer (score 1):

O método `main` é o ["ponto de entrada" de um programa Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93048/112052), é dali que o programa começa a ser executado.

No caso, você criou um `main` em cada classe, o que as torna "programas independentes": cada um pode executar sem ter ciência do outro.

Além disso, a variável `notas` criada dentro de `Numeros.main` não está visível para a classe `App`. Qualquer variável criada dentro de um método é local àquele método (ao contrário do que [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/448480/112052) afirmava (antes de ser apagada), `notas` **não** é um atributo da classe `Numeros`, e sim uma variável local do método `main`). Por isso a classe `App` não consegue encontrar a variável `notas`.

Além disso, dentro de `App.main`, criar uma instância usando `new Numeros()` **não** executa o `main` da classe `Numeros`. Na verdade você só criou uma instância da classe  `Numeros`, mas não a usou para nada.

---

Uma forma de resolver é fazer com que a classe `Numeros` retorne o array de notas que foram lidas. Assim, na classe `App` você obtém esse array e ordena:

```
public class Numeros {
    public float[] lerNotas() {
        int numAlunos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Forneca a qtde de alunos"));
        float notas[] = new float[numAlunos];

        for (int i = 0; i < numAlunos; i++) {
            notas[i] = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Forneca nota do aluno"));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numAlunos; i++) {
            System.out.println("Nota: " + notas[i]);
        }
        return notas; // retorna o array de notas
    }
}

public class App {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Numeros nm = new Numeros();
        float[] notas = nm.lerNotas(); // obter as notas
        // faz a ordenação
        for (int i = 1; i < notas.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (notas[i] > notas[j]) {
                    float temp = notas[i];
                    notas[i] = notas[j];
                    notas[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Notas ordenadas:");
        for (int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Nota: " + notas[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Outro detalhe é que tinha alguns `;` a mais. Quando você faz isso:

```
for (int i = 1; i < notas.length; i++);
{  etc... }
```

Você está dizendo que dentro do `for` não tem nada (ou tem um "bloco vazio"), pois o `;` indica que não há nada dentro deste `for`. E o que vem a seguir (o bloco `{ etc... }` **não** fará parte do `for`.

É por isso que o programa diz que não consegue encontrar o `i` nem o `j`. Eles só existem dentro do respectivo `for` em que foram declaradas, mas como o `for` terminou no `;`, o bloco que vem a seguir não consegue ver essas variáveis (já que ele não faz parte do `for`).

O mesmo vale para o `;` logo depois do `if (notas[i] > notas[j])`, logo depois dos parênteses não é para ter ponto-e-vírgula, senão o bloco que vem a seguir não fará parte do `if`. Enfim, retire esses `;` daí.

---

Outra alternativa é deixar o método `lerNotas` estático. Como ele não depende de nenhum estado específico da classe `Numeros`, não tem porque criar uma instância só para usar o método:

```
public class Numeros {
    // mudei o método para static
    public static float[] lerNotas() {
        // resto do código é igual ao anterior
    }
}
public class App {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // como lerNotas é static, não precisa criar uma instância de Numeros
        float[] notas = Numeros.lerNotas();
        // resto do código é igual ao anterior
    }
}
```